# Solve the following limit.

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, inverse-function

$\lim_{x\to 1} [\sin^{-1} x]$ ; where [.] is the 'Greatest Integer Function'.

---

The left hand limit will be $ [π/2]$ = $1$. But how can there be a right hand limit (as $ 'x'$ can't take values greater than $1$)? The answer in my textbook is given as $1$. But how can the limit exist when there is no right hand limit because for a limit to exist, LHL should be equal to the RHL.

Comment: RHL does exist, just ask wolfram alpha for values of x>1

Comment: But even the domain of arcsin is [-1,1].

Comment: so why there is a value for arcsin of 2?

Comment: @Arjang https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187719/how-to-find-the-arcsin-2

Comment: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arcsin+2

Comment: You were right to question how the limit can exist, without LHL = RHL it doesnt exist.

Comment: It's quite possible that the book implicitly considers $x$ restricted to the domain of the function: $\displaystyle\lim_{\substack{x\to1\\x\in[-1,1]}}\lfloor\arcsin x\rfloor=1$

Comment: @SiddharthGarg If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks! https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\arcsin x$ is only defined for $x\in [-1,1]$ thus the limit is to be assumed as $x\to1^-$.

Comment: why? by definition of limit, limit exists only when RHL = LHL, what is the basis that justifies this assumption?

Comment: @Arjang The definition of limits from one side is absolutely consistent and used. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function

Comment: that is one sided limit, it is not same thing as limit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit

Comment: @Arjang that is why the limit needs to be assumed as x\to 1^-, for arcsinx the RHS limit is meaningless

Comment: Actually the RHS limit does exist in complex domain, but if we accept it does not exist, then LHS limit exists, RHS does not exist and therefore limit does not exist, the book is wrong, OP is correct to question the book.

Comment: Often also for $\log x$ usually $x\to0$ is indicated and that obviously means $x\to0^+$ since the limit for $x\to 0^-$ is meaningless.

Comment: so they abuse the notation, OP correctly stated that limit exists when LHS limit = RHS limit. People being lazy and not exact does not indicate that limit exists. Although it does exist in complex domain.

Comment: What I claim is that in the case of $arcsin x$ you can't consider the RHS limit in 1 because the domain is [-1,1] thus the RHS limit can't be defined at all. Thus when you write $x\to 1$ it is to be intended$ x\to 1^-$.

Comment: Cant do that, because $x \to 1$ means both $x \to 1^+ = x \to 1^-$, it is not  consistent for it to also sometimes only mean $x \to 1^+$ and some other time to only mean $x \to 1^-$ exclusively.

Comment: @Arjang I've understood your point but in this case I think that the notation is cleraly indicating that the limit has to be considered at LHS. For instance, It's a different case from the limit $\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\to0$.

Comment: @Arjang *Your* definition of limit requires both sides. Other commonly found definitions don't and there's no *absolute right or wrong* here. It's a matter of conventions.

Comment: @egreg : That is not my definition of limit, it is how limit is defined. The OP mentioned that himself as well. I dont know any definition of limit were the limit is defined and $ LHL$neq RHL$.

Comment: @Arjang You don’t, but I do.

Comment: @egreg I don't understand how that definition can be consistent with the common definition of limit. Of course you are welcome to your own definition and extensions as long as they are consistent,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right to question the book, it is wrong, the limit does not exist, only RHS limit exists, but not the LHS limit ( In complex domain LHS limit also exists, but that will be part of Complex analysis course).

For your purposes the book is wrong, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit